# Why is SPLIT_PART working when I create a view but not when updating a table column?

Tags: postgresql, view, syntax-error

I've been using SPLIT_PART when creating views without issues and just tried updating a column in a table using the same syntax but am getting this error:

> SQL Error [42601]: Unterminated string literal started at position 0
>   in SQL ', 0)). Expected  char

From the following sql:

```
update table1
    set email1 = split_part(emails_combined,';',1);
```

**Why does this work when creating a view but not when updating a column in a table?**

Is there a way I can get this to work in table? I have a column with a list of emails separated by semicolons that I want to split and fill separate columns with each email.

Update -- Here is a sample of the data in the column I'm trying to split:

```
    testing@123.net;    
    ;jon@loremipsum.com;jason@sample.net;test@123.com
    jon@loremipsum.com;jason@sample.net;test@123.com
    ;testing@123.net
    ;info@loremipsum.com;misc@random.com;info@stuff.com
    ;  
    jon@loremipsum.com;jason@sample.net;test@123.com
```

There are rows where the only value is a ';'. There are no null rows.

Update: I randomly tried moving the closing ; down another line and the SQL worked. Like this:

```
   update table1
    set email1 = split_part(emails_combined,';',1)
;
```

Why would moving the closing semicolon like this make a difference?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, as the underlying data may be the source of the error.

Comment: added sample data

Comment: There's probably some part of the query/data you are not showing us that's causing the issue. Your update statement works perfectly fine see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6eb5fcf38f99848ee25bc6611866c2b4)

Comment: Yeah, see the update in my question from a second ago. I got it to work by moving the closing semicolon down one line. Do you have any idea why that made it work?

Comment: Which tool are you using to run it? Maybe there's an issue in parsing semicolons for that tool.

Comment: Dbeaver community edition v5.3.2 and I'm running Postgres 11.1.

Comment: Your SQL should work fine. Maybe the preceding line has a problem, or you didn't use proper single quotes, or something is wrong with the client application.

Comment: I don't think so--I tried the query in a new SQL window, so it was the first line. Whenever something weird like this happens opening a new window usually works for me, but not this time.

Comment: You can check if the same problem occurs while using another client eg pgadmin.